# Why is QueueClient not disposable

Tags: c#, servicebus

Why is QueueClient not disposable? It has a Close method. Do I always have to call close. The documentation says:

> Sends a cleanup message to Service Bus to signal the completion of the usage of an entity. (Inherited from ClientEntity.)

Do I need this if I only use the client for sending?

Comment: If you want to make this easier, you could create your own `IQueueClient` interface that *does* implement `IDisposable`, and then implement it as an adapter of Service Bus's `QueueClient`. See the [Adapter pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html)

Comment: That was weird. There was a comment here before linking to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh851740.aspx That helped me to understand that they are in fact thread safe and should not be disposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

> Reusing factories and clients
>   Service Bus client objects, such as QueueClient or MessageSender, are created through a MessagingFactory object, which also provides internal management of connections. It is recommended that you do not close messaging factories or queue, topic, and subscription clients after you send a message, and then re-create them when you send the next message. Closing a messaging factory deletes the connection to the Service Bus service, and a new connection is established when recreating the factory. Establishing a connection is an expensive operation that you can avoid by reusing the same factory and client objects for multiple operations. You can safely use these client objects for concurrent asynchronous operations and from multiple threads.

Proof link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#reusing-factories-and-clients

Comment: The same link says: "Service Bus client objects, such as implementations of IQueueClient or IMessageSender, should be registered for dependency injection as singletons (or instantiated once and shared)."
Shouldn't `IQueueClient` implement `IDisposable` for a dependency injection container to be able to dispose it properly?